# how to access and delete play store's search history?

Tags: android, google-play

i want to access the Google Play Store(formerly known as Android Market) search history from within my app.
after accessing the history i want to delete some of the items.

This feature is available in many apps but i am not able to access it.
thanks is advance.

EDIT: I want to implement this programmatically from with-in my app on a click of button

Answer (score 2):

I delete search history market ,but not detail history.

```
public boolean isHistoryMarket(Context paramContext)
{
    if (paramContext == null && isGoogleMarketInstalled())
        return false;

        try
        {
            new SearchRecentSuggestions(paramContext,
                    "com.google.android.finsky.RecentSuggestionsProvider",
                    1).clearHistory();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: How did you fix the SecurityException? java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.finsky.providers.RecentSuggestionsProvider

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings --> Apps --> Google Play Services --> Clear Data.

Comment: i need to do this programmatically

Comment: You can't, your app won't have access unless you have root. Even then I don't imagine it would be easy to do. I'm not sure even how you would do it if you could, sorry.

Comment: applications like History Eraser allow this.

Comment: thanks for your concern. please help me if you get the solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228922/clear-android-maps-history-programmatically

Comment: That answer should help you, you just need to look for the package name of the Market app instead of the maps app.#

Comment: will try this and keep you posted.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Play App -> Menu -> Settings -> Clear Search history

Comment: i need to do this programmatically.
Please check the Edit. Thanks