# Open Google maps without address or lat/long Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have some basic issue in Google Maps(Android).  From my app, I want to open Google maps homepage alone. I do not need to pass any address or lat/long via intent. Just open the Google maps.

```
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

This code helps but only problem is the previous search route(if we did on Google maps) still shows while opening the google maps.  I want to clear any routes if exists and open the Google maps.  The idea is user will search the address manually from the Google Maps.  From my App I just need to open the Google maps.

Any help!

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, you can open Google Maps application in Driving Mode via intent as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787692/6950238) of [Jason Maderski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8492452/jason-maderski):

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("google.navigation:/?free=1&mode=d&entry=fnls"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4283908/6950238) answer of [icyerasor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314089/icyerasor).